How can I use a tileGrid to limit the requests send from an RLayerTile via the url property in RLayers?
I am working on a Next js application which fetches ortophotos and displays them on a map. The photos are displayed with an RLayerTile (from RLayers) through the url property. I want the url to be fetched, only within a certain extent. So by having the extent of the orthophoto, and creating a tileGrid with it, which is then used in RLayerTile, I should be able to limit the requests, so they are sent only for the extent. However, it does not work.
I am certain the extent is set properly, and is in the right projection, but despite that no orthophoto tiles are being requested. The only request that is sent is for coordinates such as this ..../1/0/0.png, which is not valid, and not within the extent.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

If ..../1/0/0.png is not valid then the origin of the tile grid is different to the extent.  See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/15105
